# How to deploy new code to Elastic Beanstalk and simultaneously change configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've enabled immutable deployments and configuration changes for my app. I want to deploy a new version that relies on an environment variable that is not currently set in Elastic Beanstalk.

- If I deploy the code first, it won't work because the environment variable would be missing.
- If I deploy the variable first, I'd cause an unnecessary termination of the current instances and creation of new ones.

How could I set the variable and upload my code *simultaneously*? Currently, it appears that I can only do one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set environment variables via [`.ebextensions` settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html).

```
option_settings:
  - option_name:  option name
    value:  option value
  - option_name:  option name
    value:  option value
```

Granted, you wouldn't want to commit to source control if they're sensitive values. [See `eb deploy` manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) for details on how it behaves in relation to Git - you may need to do a local `git commit`, run `eb deploy`, then revert the local commit, for example.